# Variance moment inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random variable $X$. Is it necessarily true that 
$$Var(X^3)\cdot Var(X) \ge Var(X^2)? $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not.

Suppose $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable of parameter $1/2$. Then $X$ and $X^3$ follow exactly the same law. And $Var(X)=1/4$.

Consequently $Var(X^3)\cdot Var(X)=1/16 < 1/4=Var(X^2)$.